# Show that $\frac{f(z)}{z }$ does not have a limit as z goes to 0

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)=\frac{z^5}{|z^4|}$  if $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.
Show that $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ does not have a limit as $z\to 0$.

I'm not sure how to start on this one.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: z is talking about complex numbers ie. z=x+iy

Comment: Yes, but you can also write them as $z = r e^{i\varphi}$. Here, that's more convenient to use.

Comment: @Rich, Indeed if the such a function has limit $l$, then for each fixed $\phi_0$ you can write:
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow0} g(re^{i\phi_0})=l$$

Comment: I can set the top up right but i'm still unsure on how you would write the |z4| out using polar coordinates.  Is it possible to solve this using u(x,y) and v(x,y) with z=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)